# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass blinking when saving / focus

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, interop, office-interop

I am using VS2012 and Office 2013. Inside my Windows form I have embedded Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass. Everything works fine, except one thing: blinking of embedded word document when I gave focus to opened document or when I save document.

With saving, I have managed to partially minimize the problem with ScreenRefresh method:

```
//save to the disc
_wd.Documents[1].SaveAs(_xmlConfiguration.RootFolder + Id + _xmlConfiguration.FileExtension);                        
_wd.Documents[1].Saved = true;
//prevents blinking and occassional dissapearing of document
_wd.ScreenRefresh();
```

But the problem remains when I gave focus to document - then it blinks really hard - it dissappears and reappears for a moment. I open document programmatically and there is no hard blinking. But, with focus it blinks (if I click in it). Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Word.Application is an interface, it doesn't "blink".  Do not attempt to embed an Office window, it cannot work reliably.

Comment: I need word functionalities, because I am simply copying - pasting text from internet (for my Knowledge Base). The text is then extracted from document to solr. The document is saved on disc. What else can I do if I don't embedd office window?